# Как сделать так, чтобы при написании команды, начался обратный отсчёт?

Tags: python, aiogram

Есть переменная users, которая хранит в себе список user_id пользователей Telegram. У каждого пользователя в Базе Данных есть время в секундах, которое хранится в ячейке time_tracking.
Как сделать так, чтобы когда админ писал команду start_tracker - начинался обратный отсчёт у всех пользователей?
Я написал вот такой код, но он начинает отсчёт только у того, кто её написал (у админа)

Использую: Aiogram, SQLite

```
elif 'start_tracker'.lower() in message.text.lower():
    users = [765963392, 6537306686]
    for user in users:
        timer_seconds = int(db.get_time_tracking(user))
        new_message = await bot.send_message(user, f'{timer_seconds}')
        for seconds_left in range(timer_seconds - 1, -1, -1):
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            db.set_time_tracking(user, seconds_left)
            await new_message.edit_text(f'{seconds_left}')

        await bot.send_message(user, f'Всё!')
```